# Flutter: Image_Picker crashes app when trying to select image from gallery or camera

Tags: flutter, crash, imagepicker

When trying to upload an image on my social media app it always crashes. Its been 2 months trying to solve this issue.
Initially i was using an older flutter code which had Deprecation warnings. I have now migrated the App to AndroidX hoping to solve the issue but still it fails on opening Select image option before you even pic the image the app crashes.

Flutter Doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.24.0-10.2.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.630], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.24.0-10.2.pre at C:\Flutter
    • Framework revision 022b333a08 (5 days ago), 2020-11-18 11:35:09 -0800
    • Engine revision 07c1eed46b
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-29.10.beta)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at F:\Android\SDKs
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = F:\Android\SDKs
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\ACEHOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.16.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • DRA LX5 (mobile) • VUY9K20409902290 • android-arm • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)

• No issues found!
```

***Debug Console Errors: From the point where the App crashes***

```
I/flutter (14332): Firebase Messaging Token: dI1-F5iKBVA:APA91bHJE6Yk91vcEv3BX0h2A2KaNZMWvEALwrqYRzZ-ZoihIste67XLiwnf72OPcbvWfLm7tm4ScD8c2CzOvsiqOG7IZMd5aPfOcULEDCLrUbgJ_rFxoSE0kIQhxdpXcqMFWMp4G4E0
I/flutter (14332): Firebase Messaging Token: dI1-F5iKBVA:APA91bHJE6Yk91vcEv3BX0h2A2KaNZMWvEALwrqYRzZ-ZoihIste67XLiwnf72OPcbvWfLm7tm4ScD8c2CzOvsiqOG7IZMd5aPfOcULEDCLrUbgJ_rFxoSE0kIQhxdpXcqMFWMp4G4E0
V/jhw     (14332): call Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(1)
D/Surface (14332): Surface::disconnect(this=0x903be000,api=1)
D/Surface (14332): Surface::disconnect(this=0x903be000,api=-1)
D/Surface (14332): Surface::disconnect(this=0x903a3000,api=1)
W/ThreadedRenderer(14332): ThreadedRenderer::detachAnimators pid = 14332 threadid = 14474
V/PhoneWindow(14332): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = ViewRoot{d76c32d com.finde.med/com.finde.med.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this = DecorView@8723b57[MainActivity]
W/ThreadedRenderer(14332): ThreadedRenderer::detachAnimators pid = 14332 threadid = 14474

W/ConnectionTracker(14332): Exception thrown while unbinding
W/ConnectionTracker(14332): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lp@5595c0d
W/ConnectionTracker(14332):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1556)
W/ConnectionTracker(14332):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1642)
W/ConnectionTracker(14332):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:703)
W/ConnectionTracker(14332):     at ci.f(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217128@20.42.17 (110306-0):1)
W/ConnectionTracker(14332):     at ci.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217128@20.42.17 (110306-0):2)
W/ConnectionTracker(14332):     at lq.D(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217128@20.42.17 (110306-0):10)
W/ConnectionTracker(14332):     at lc.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217128@20.42.17 (110306-0):2)
W/ConnectionTracker(14332):     at ee.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217128@20.42.17 (110306-0):3)
W/ConnectionTracker(14332):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
W/ConnectionTracker(14332):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W/ConnectionTracker(14332):     at ix.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@204217128@20.42.17 (110306-0):6)
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

***Code for Upload Page***

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:findemed/models/user.dart';
import 'package:findemed/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:findemed/widgets/progress.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as Im;
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

class Upload extends StatefulWidget {
  final User currentUser;

  Upload({this.currentUser});

  @override
  _UploadState createState() => _UploadState();
}

class _UploadState extends State<Upload>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<Upload> {
  TextEditingController captionController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController locationController = TextEditingController();
  File file;
  bool isUploading = false;
  String postId = Uuid().v4();

  handleTakePhoto() async {
    final _picker = ImagePicker();
    PickedFile image;

    Navigator.pop(context);
    // File file 
    image = await _picker.getImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxHeight: 675,
      maxWidth: 960,
    );
    setState(() {
      this.file = File(image.path);
    });
  }

  handleChooseFromGallery() async {
    final _picker = ImagePicker();
    PickedFile image;

    Navigator.pop(context);
    // File file (removed)
    image = await _picker.getImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      );
    setState(() {
      this.file = File(image.path);
    });
  }

  selectImage(parentContext) {
    return showDialog(
      context: parentContext,
      builder: (context) {
        return SimpleDialog(
          title: Text("Create Post"),
          children: <Widget>[
            SimpleDialogOption(
                child: Text("Photo with Camera"), 
                onPressed: handleTakePhoto
                ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
                child: Text("Image from Gallery"),
                onPressed: handleChooseFromGallery
                ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              child: Text("Cancel"),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  

  Container buildSplashScreen() {
    return Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.6),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          SvgPicture.asset('assets/images/upload.svg', height: 170.0),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "Upload Image",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                onPressed: () => selectImage(context)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  } 

  clearImage() {
    setState(() {
      file = null;
    });
  }

  compressImage() async {
    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path = tempDir.path;
    Im.Image imageFile = Im.decodeImage(file.readAsBytesSync());
    final compressedImageFile = File('$path/img_$postId.jpg')
      ..writeAsBytesSync(Im.encodeJpg(imageFile, quality: 85));
    setState(() {
      file = compressedImageFile;
    });
  }

  Future<String> uploadImage(imageFile) async {
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask =
        storageRef
        .child("post_$postId.jpg")
        .putFile(imageFile);
    StorageTaskSnapshot storageSnap = await uploadTask
        .onComplete;
    String downloadUrl = await storageSnap.ref
        .getDownloadURL();
   return downloadUrl;

  }

  createPostInFirestore(
      {String mediaUrl, String location, String description}) {
    postsRef
        .doc(widget.currentUser.id)
        .collection("userPosts")
        .doc(postId)
        .set({
      "postId": postId,
      "ownerId": widget.currentUser.id,
      "username": widget.currentUser.username,
      "mediaUrl": mediaUrl,
      "description": description,
      "location": location,
      "timestamp": timestamp,
      "likes": {},
    });
  }

  handleSubmit() async {
    setState(() {
      isUploading = true;
    });
    await compressImage();
    String mediaUrl = await uploadImage(file);
    createPostInFirestore(
      mediaUrl: mediaUrl,
      location: locationController.text,
      description: captionController.text,
    );
    captionController.clear();
    locationController.clear();
    setState(() {
      file = null;
      isUploading = false;
      postId = Uuid().v4();
    });
  }

  Scaffold buildUploadForm() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
            onPressed: clearImage),
        title: Text(
          "Caption Post",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        actions: [
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: isUploading ? null : () => handleSubmit(),
            child: Text(
              "Post",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          isUploading ? linearProgress(context) : Text(""),
          Container(
            height: 220.0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
            child: Center(
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      image: FileImage(file),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage:
                  CachedNetworkImageProvider(widget.currentUser.photoUrl),
            ),
            title: Container(
              width: 250.0,
              child: TextField(
                controller: captionController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Write a caption...",
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.pin_drop,
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              size: 35.0,
            ),
            title: Container(
              width: 250.0,
              child: TextField(
                controller: locationController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Where was this photo taken?",
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 200.0,
            height: 100.0,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: RaisedButton.icon(
              label: Text(
                "Use Current Location",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              ),
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              onPressed: getUserLocation,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.my_location,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  getUserLocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    List<Placemark> placemarks = await Geolocator()
        .placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    Placemark placemark = placemarks[0];
    String completeAddress =
        '${placemark.subThoroughfare} ${placemark.thoroughfare}, ${placemark.subLocality} ${placemark.locality}, ${placemark.subAdministrativeArea}, ${placemark.administrativeArea} ${placemark.postalCode}, ${placemark.country}';
    print(completeAddress);
    String formattedAddress = "${placemark.subLocality}, ${placemark.locality}, ${placemark.country}";
    locationController.text = formattedAddress;
  }

 bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    return file == null ? buildSplashScreen() : buildUploadForm();
  }
}
```

Comment: hello @Ace did you get the solution to this issue..? Am on android 9, compileversion 30, buildversion 30

Comment: No hey. Its been pending since. We request on git to have the flutter team look into it but no luck as yet.

Answer (score 0):

An `IllegalArgumentException` is usually thrown when the parameter used in a constructor or function is invalid. Though from what I see here, the cause of the issue is unclear.

This error is similar to the issue posted on this [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72898). Have you tried running the latest stable version with the plugin and see if the behavior is the same? [Another solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72898#issuecomment-755352137) that worked is to isolate the plugins being used. Try removing other plugins aside from `image_picker` and see if there's any error thrown. It's also likely that a different plugin might've been causing the issue.